# Typesafe routehandlers with catch-all segments in NextJs 13.2?

Tags: typescript, next.js13

I would like to use NextJs's new API route handler within their /app directory using the slug along these lines:

http://localhost:3000/api/12/24/test

But when I do that I get this in the console:

> Number 1: undefined Number 2: undefined String: undefined

This is my route.ts file:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

interface MyParams {
  num1: number;
  num2: number;
  str: string;
}

export async function GET(
  request: NextRequest,
  { params: { num1, num2, str } }: { params: MyParams }
) {
  console.log(`Number 1: ${num1}`);
  console.log(`Number 2: ${num2}`);
  console.log(`String: ${str}`);

  return new NextResponse("Hello, Next.js!");
}
```

Does anyone how have any advice on how I could access these different slug parameters in a typesafe way?

Update: this code works, but then it treats all input parameters are string, which isn't really what I want.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(
  request: NextRequest,
  { params }: { params: { id: string[] } }
) {
  const [num1, num2, str] = params.id;
  console.log(`Number 1: ${num1}`);
  console.log(`Number 2: ${num2}`);
  console.log(`String: ${str}`);

  return new NextResponse("Hello, Next.js!");
}
```

Comment: You must have a file path (relative from the `api/` directory) of `[num1]/[num2]/[str].ts` if you wish to have URL params. Yes, those are brackets in folder and file names.

Comment: Thanks, that would work, but were thinking of passing quite a few parameters to this API function so that the directory structure would be quite complex very quickly. Where therefore thinking of using the Catch-all Segments described here:
https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#catch-all-segments